# get value from localStorage and append it to class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, local-storage

I'm messing around with setting data into `localStorage`, but I'm trying to extract a value and have it populate into an empty `span` on a specific page load.

This is what I've been messing with, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to go about it:

```
    if($(".body-class-name").length > 0){
      $('.title span').append($(localStorage.getItem("first_name")));
  }
```

The only other examples I've tried to work with deal with external JSON data and that's a little *too* much for what I'm trying to work with.

Comment: No. My bad. I've updated my code to reflect what I'm trying to mess with. Thanks!

Comment: We need more context. When should this happen? When page loads, on some click? Do you want to append the storage value to the span or do you want to clear the span and insert new value?

Comment: @Poku - updated my code. Sorry. And yes, I want to insert the stored value into the empty span.

Comment: But (again), that code targets all `span` elements that are descendants of any element that uses the `title` class. Is that what you are after?

Comment: _"but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to go about it"_ What is issue with `javascript` at Question?

Answer (score 0):

The code does what it is suppose to. You could improve abit.

```
     if($(".body-class-name").length > 0){
       var firstname = $(localStorage.getItem("first_name");
       if (firstname) {
          $('#title-text').text(firstname));
       }
      }
```

Then there is some missing context in your post. But i would also look at:

Using text instead of append if you don\t want to keep append firstnames to that span.

And as others mentioned in comments be aware of your selector. I changed it to query for an ID instead.

Comment: What is issue with `javascript` at Question?

Comment: As i wrote in my answer. The code does what it is suppose but OP asks if he doing it correct and i supplied some improvements

Comment: How do you know that `javascript` at Question renders expected result? OP has not indicated what expected result is, whether code at OP renders expected result or not, nor provided a minimal complete verifiable example demonstrating code at OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $ ( ".body-class-name" ). length > 0 ){ 
  $ ( '.title span' ). append ( localStorage . getItem ( "first_name" )); }
```

The $() isn't needed around the localStorage.getItem()

Comment: _"The $() isn't needed around the localStorage.getItem()"_ How can you be certain?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need using load event.
Load event is for assets files, you can use ready event.

In basically jQuery code run after document ready.

You just need to wrap with function, For example:

```
<h1 class="title">Hello again <span>User</span></h1>
<br/>
<label>
  Enter your name here:
  <input name="firstname" />
</label>

<script>
(function($){
  $("input[name='firstname']").change(function(){
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("first_name", $(this).val() );
  });

  // Load store
  $('.title span').text( localStorage.getItem( "first_name" ) );

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

[Live code here](https://codepen.io/WebStorm-IL/pen/EmEdoL)